# children().length is returning an unexpected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Everything can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/dweiliu/NBFMq/3/

This is the relevant code in question:

```
$('article.weeklyStandings').each(function(){
   var numPlayers = $(this).children('table tr').length;
   $(this).children('h2').append(" - " + numPlayers + " Players");
});
```

I have potentially multiple tables of data with results as displayed in the jsfiddle. I want to point out the number of players who played on any given week by looking up the number of rows in the table.

Why is `$(this).children('table tr').length;` returning 0 on jsfiddle? Note that on my local machine, this same code is returning 3.

Comment: `.children` only gets direct descendants you need to use `.find`

Comment: Thanks Pete. This was my problem. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is:

1. `children()` will only look at direct children. You'll want to use `find()` which will find all the `table tr` within each article.
2. If you count all of the `tr`'s you will have end up with an extra because your heading will also be counted as a player. For this reason you can subtract 1 from the length of `tr`'s.

**Solution**

Here is an example implementing the above solutions: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/NBFMq/5/)

```
var numPlayers = $(this).find('table tr').length -1;
```

**Alternative (the one I would use)**

As you have a `record` class on your player tr's, you could use `.record` in your selector instead, this will provide better readability and flexibility if you wish to add other rows in the future that should not be counted as a player: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/NBFMq/9/)

```
var numPlayers = $(this).find('.record').length;
```

**Another Alternative**

You could also use context selectors like `$('.record', this)` instead of `$(this).find('.record')`, but in my opinion it's easier to read `find()` chaining. Also, as context selectors internally have to use `find()` anyway, using `find()` directly will perform slightly better: [**Performance test**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel)

Comment: Thanks! I switched .children with .find and it resolved my issue.

Comment: @Dave, that switch alone wouldn't fix your issue as your selector was `table tr` and your heading was also a `tr`. You'll want to either subtract one from that or change your selector to look for `.record` as I showed in the two examples above.

Comment: I added a "- 1" to the end of numPlayers on my actual site. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. After looking at all the suggestions, I think I'll use yours for the very reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var numPlayers = $(this).children('table tr').length;
```

to

```
var numPlayers = $('.record', this).length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NBFMq/11/)

Comment: Thanks. I just used .find instead of .children because the latter only gets direct descendants. That worked.Switching the selector would easily have worked if I were only going after 1 table but I needed it to scale to use more table.

Comment: Thanks! I like your solution better than my original fix with a -1 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var numPlayers = $(this).children('table tr').length;
```

to

```
var numPlayers = $(this).find('table tr').length-1;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NBFMq/12/)**

`.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well

Answer (score 0):

Change children() by find() in your numPlayer affectation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.record').each(function(){
        var cells = $(this).children('td');
        var gamesWon = parseInt(cells[1].innerText);
        var gamesPlayed = parseInt(cells[2].innerText);
        var winningPercentage = (gamesWon / gamesPlayed * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        $(cells[3]).html(winningPercentage);
    });
    $('article.weeklyStandings').each(function(){
        var numPlayers = $(this).find('tr.record').length;
        $(this).children('h2').append(" - " + numPlayers + " Players");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xz9ZM/)

Comment: Thanks! I switched .children with .find and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to other answers:

```
var numPlayers = $(this).children('table').find('tr').length;
```

Comment: Thanks! I switched .children with .find and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `.children()` function only looks at immediate descendants, so those that are one level down in the DOM. What you're saying is "look for a `<tr>` that's inside a `<table>` and is also the direct descendant of the `<article class="weeklyStandings">` element"; that won't ever be the case because the `<table>` is between those two.

You should use `.find()` instead, as well as modify your selector so that it doesn't include your header row:

```
$(this).find('table tr.records').length;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually need it to scale to multiple tables with the class "record". Anyways, switching to .find instead of .children was the trick.